# Using VBA to copy a spreadsheet from a secondary workbook into the primary one

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I need to take a spreadsheet and compare it with a spreadsheet from another workbook.  I know that I can do this using VBA, but I will need to copy a spreadsheet from another workbook so that both spreadsheets will reside within the same workbook and be accessible for comparison.  How do I copy a spreadsheet from one workbook into another using VBA?

Comment: Your question is too general and unclear. Please try to give more details

Comment: Please post what you have tried, and the results that don't work...and ask for help.

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote the question to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: Just search title of the question on google you will find many examples

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy the worksheets over to compare them. Simply open both WorkBooks and and set reference to there WorkSheets.

```
Sub CompareWorkBooks()
    Dim wbPending As Workbook
    Dim wsPending As Worksheet

    Set wbPending = Workbooks("Items Pending")
    Set wsPending = wsPending.Worksheet("Items")

    Dim wbRecieved As Workbook
    Dim wsRecieved As Worksheet

    Set wbRecieved = Workbooks("Items Recieved")
    Set wsRecieved = Worksheet("Items")

End Sub
```

If you provide names for Workbooks & WorkSheets and provide column information, we can give you better answers in a shorter period of time.  Don't be afraid to post your code either.

If you want a user to select the target workbook and worksheet:

- Create a userform
- Declare targetWorkbook and tartgetWorksheet at the top of the code module
- Add a  command button and a combo box
- When the button is clicked a file dialog is opened
- A reference is now set to the open file
- The names of all the worksheets are added to the combo
- Changing the combo box value will set the refernce to tartgetWorksheet

```html
Option Explicit
Public targetWorkbook As Workbook
Public tartgetWorksheet As Worksheet

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set targetWorkbook = getTargetWorkbook

    If targetWorkbook = Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sowmthing went wrong", vbCritical, "Try Again"
    Else
        For Each ws In targetWorkbook.Worksheets
            ComboBox1.AddItem ws.Name
        Next
    End If

End Function

Function getTargetWorkbook() As Workbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
        Set getTargetWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Function

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Set tartgetWorksheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is it possible to prompt the user to select the two workbooks each time the program is run?

Comment: Do you want a file browser dialog to open for them to choose the workbook?  Does the worksheet always have the same name or does the user need to select that too?

Comment: The worksheets will have different names, and a file browser dialog is preferred.